# How to read files from a resources folder in java?

Tags: java

Hello: I have not found anything useful on the web, so I ask the question. How can I read files from the resource folder?
I have a source folder (src) and a resources folder (res). Both are specified in Java as a source folder. I tried to use: `new File(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("shader.glsl").getFile());`
but it didn't work. Please do not be too strict just ask if I forgot something to mention.

These are the errors that I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: shader.glsl (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.leocat.game.shader.ShaderProgram.loadShader(ShaderProgram.java:54)
    at com.leocat.game.shader.ShaderProgram.init(ShaderProgram.java:18)
    at com.leocat.game.shader.StaticShader.init(StaticShader.java:8)
    at com.leocat.game.states.GameState.init(GameState.java:29)
    at com.leocat.game.Game.init(Game.java:91)
    at com.leocat.game.Game.updateGLFW(Game.java:60)
    at com.leocat.game.Game.run(Game.java:132)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can please  provide some more information what type of project you and what you did yet

Comment: do you have any error?

Comment: "but it didn't work" - please could you clarify what you mean by that? If you could provide a [mcve] that would really help us to help you.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the code for method `loadShader()` in class `ShaderProgram` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `shader.glsl` file in your **resource** folder. I.e. when you build **jar** file it will copy to the **jar root**. Then you can read it as stream:

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream in = classloader.getResourceAsStream("/shader.glsl");
```

Answer (score 7):

Dont use `File` API to get resource files because it may work eg during development in IDE (because all compiled filesa are placed on disc) and will not work after build and deployment of JAR (because JAR content is not accessible to native file system)

Instead of getting file, get resource stream directly. With file API you would have to get `FileInputStream` at some point anyway. So to make it work everywhere use

```
InputStream in = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("shader.glsl");
```

In this case, `shader.glsl` must be present in `resource` folder (if you are using maven) or to be more precise and universal, it must be compiled into root of JAR file. If it is nested in JAR you will have to use `/path/to/resource/shader.glsl` to get that resource

Comment: can you point to the source please?

Answer (score 1):

For accessing a resource from the classpath

```
new ClassPathResource("data/employees.dat", this.getClass().getClassLoader());

new ClassPathResource("../../../data/employees.dat", Example.class).getFile();
```

retrieve your resource with getResource:

```
resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:data/employees.dat");
```

By ApplicationContext

```
context.getResource("classpath:data/employees.dat");
```

Reading as an InputStream

```
InputStream resource = new ClassPathResource("data/employees.dat").getInputStream();
```

Comment: Isn't that Spring???

Answer (score 1):

You may use Guava's [`Resources`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Resources.html) class to safely access resources. It has convenience methods to reading them as `String` or `List<String>` of lines. Also it will fail with more meaningful exceptions in case of misconfiguration.